# hiding edittext & Background Image retraction in <AbsoluteLayout>

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-edittext, absolutelayout

for design layout in my app, i use `<AbsoluteLayout>` for my main layout & set a image for background such :

```
    android:background="@drawable/main"
```

But in typing in edittext(s) i have tow problem:

1. hiding edittext(s)
2. Background Image retraction
3. Problem with textview, when i change position with mouse(it's right when i change X/Y position in Properties)

   **this problems is from my layout designing or another Bugs?**

Comment: <Absoulte layout> is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using AbsoluteLayout, it was deprecated 4 years ago and had a lot of troubles like that one.

Use a RelativeLayout instead:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: tanx , but when i use RelativeLayout all widgets deform when a widget change position.

Comment: They shouldnt deform, and the sooner you learn to use relative the better, deprecated things are likely to dissapear in some version, so better have a tough time now and save the saeid of the future from having a huge problem ;)